# Differentiating Webhooks

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-5, webhooks

I'm trying to setup to receive webhooks and then do something with that data. I have managed to receieve a specific webhook and then parse the data and use that data. However, since I am very new to webhooks, one part troubles me and I'm not sure how to go about resolving it.

With the provider that I am using webhooks with, I setup an endpoint. They will now send over 100 different webhook events straight to my endpoint. Now they have different xml parent node for each event. I am only really interested in maybe 3 events. What I am trying to find out is how do I differentiate these events?

One way is to try to parse the first node and then check against white list and then if its one of the ones I want, I parse into a specific object and off I go. But to me that feels rather clunky and wondering if I am missing something and there is a better way to go about this.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Webhook()
{
    var requestContent = GetRequestContent();
    var type = GetTypeBasedOnFirstNode(requestContent);
    var document = _xmlService.DeserializeFromString<type>(requestContent);
}
```

Comment: can't you register different webhooks on different URLs ? Its looks like all your different webhooks get fired on same endpoint.

Comment: Yes they seem to fire on same endpoint.

Comment: if you can make them fire on different endpoints, you're golden.

Comment: Some webhook sources allow selecting only specific events for just this case. Not sure what your source permits.

Comment: It would appear I cannot so I'm stuck finding a solution better than what I suggested above.